# Loading Subsequent Videos into QTMovieView with setMovie: not working

Tags: xcode, cocoa, qtkit

I am working on a program which has a rigid set of 'stages' for video recording... Think of it like a Video-Booth.  I am running the program on OSX Lion, coded entirely in Cocoa.

The 'stages' are as follows:

1. Welcome Screen
2. Begin Recording
3. Playback Video
4. Confirmation for Saving/Deleting

Stages 1, 2, and 4 work perfectly every time.  And Stage 3 works perfectly the FIRST time.

On the second, or later, time of going through the process, the video playback (which is done by a `QTMovieView` embedded within a NSPanel) is still set to the video from the FIRST run-through.

I have two methods set-up, one which is activated by a button press, the other by other code in the program.  BOTH of these methods DO FIRE, I am positive.  What I don't know is why `[mPlaybackView setMovie: lclMov]` is not setting the new movie...

To clarify (based on the code below):

- I HAVE looked prior to starting the playback to make sure the file at `TEMP_STORE` actually exists (and is the new file, not the old one)
- I HAVE also tried replacing `[QTMovie movieWithFile:TEMP_STORE error:&err];` with `[[QTMovie alloc] initWithFile:TEMP_STORE error:&err]` (as per a recommendation I saw online somewhere)
- The file at `TEMP_STORE` is a '.mov' file recorded by another code segment in my program

Any and all help is appreciated!!!

### CODE

```
- (IBAction) startPlayback: (id) sender {
    NSError *err;
    QTMovie *lclMov = [QTMovie movieWithFile:TEMP_STORE error:&err];

    [instrPlayback orderOut:nil];

    if (err != nil) {
        [errorMessage setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [err localizedDescription]]];
        [errorDialog makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
    } else {
        [self writeString: CMD_PROCEED];

        [mPlaybackView setMovie:lclMov];
        [mPlaybackView gotoBeginning:nil];
        [playbackDialog makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
    }
}

- (void) stopPlayback {
    QTMovie *lclMov = [mPlaybackView movie];
    if ([lclMov canUpdateMovieFile]) {
        if (![lclMov updateMovieFile]) {
            [errorMessage setStringValue:@"Error Applying Updates to MOV File.\nAsk Lab Attendant for Help."];
            [errorDialog makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
            }
        }

        [playbackDialog orderOut:nil];
}
```

Comment: i had same problem....if movie is already loaded in mPlaybackView then set it to nil and load again.  for example: if(lclMov) { [mPlaybackView setMovie:nil]; [mPlaybackView setMovie:lclMov] }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To people who come upon this in the future, here was my soltuion:

I guess I was being sort of dumb ... but I knew it had something to do with deallocating the video from memory.  My resulting solution was to import the QuickTime framework (which, as I had not a clue, was different than the QTKit framework) and use the `DisposeMovie()` method from `Movies.h`

Such a simple solution, and it gave me so much trouble.

Good luck to all the developers out there who may run into this same problem :)

Comment: Can you show some code of what you actually did to solve the problem using DisposeMovie?